# Finding the pdf given that $Y=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with the pdf given by

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\beta} e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}, &  x > 0 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Find the pdf of $Y = \sqrt{X}$.

My attempt:

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(\sqrt{X}\le Y) = P(X\le Y^2) $$

$$ f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}  \frac{2ye^{-\frac{y}\beta}}{\beta}, & \text{if }  y >0 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Why the arctangent?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin, I made the corrections.

Comment: Your $f_Y(y)$ should be written in terms of $y$ completely (no $x$ here ).

Comment: It should be $y^2$ instead of $y$ in the exponent. $ f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}  \frac{2ye^{-\frac{y^2}\beta}}{\beta}, & \text{if }  y >0 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $